# Overwriting environment style

Tags: environments

How can I change the style of an element in LaTeX ?

I would like to do some basic modifications on some environments. For example changing the text size in `quotation`, margins in `verbatim` or the line spacing in `itemize` blocks.

I want the change to be made on every block of the document.

How can I rewrite some style definitions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you can write your own environment that wraps around the one you want to change. For example

```
\newenvironment{quotingalt}
  {% \begin{quotingalt}
   \large% Change font size
   \begin{quote}%
  }{% \end{quotingalt}
   \end{quote}%
  }
```

In fact, this is how many of the default environments in the standard classes are written. For example, consider the `quote` environment from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

The above code initiates the `list` environment with `\list` and ends it with `\endlist` to form `quote`.

Since the environment has some scope, changes are localized so you don't have to worry about resetting them. The [`environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) allows a more intuitive command-like interface to environments, providing `\BODY` for the grabbed content inside it:

```
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\NewEnviron{quotingalt}{%
  \large% Change the font size
  \begin{quote}\BODY\end{quote}%
}
```

Alternative approaches include keeping the original name and modifying it using a patch (with [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and friends) or a complete redefinition with your style added.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do it that way. I was hoping to be able easily to keep the same name (and not change everything in my doc) but it's ok.

Comment: @MartinTrigaux: It is possible to keep the same environment name using a patch (as suggested in my answer) or by "replacing" the names. This all depends on the specific environment you're interested in changing (since arguments might play a part in this). If you could provide a description of this environment, more help could be provided. My alternative solution is to wrap the environment with you modifications, which provides a general result.